# What are the units of the channels of the SparkFun NIR Spectral Sensor?

Tags: sparkfun, spectroscopy

The product is https://www.sparkfun.com/products/14351 and the datasheet can be found at https://cdn.sparkfun.com/assets/1/b/7/3/b/AS7263.pdf. I'm not entirely sure about the difference between the "calibrated" values vs. raw values, as in calibrated against what?

Finally, if the units does turns out to be in voltage or some other unit, how does it relate to reflectance/intensity?

Comment: They might or might not give details into how exactly they are calibrated.

Answer (score 1):

Raw values are what the sensor measures, with known error or tolerance, and the sensor contains calibration data how to remove measurement errors.

The numbers are units of (μW/cm2).